# Selenium skips javascript popup click

Tags: python, selenium

Unable to access the site from outside,but I uploaded html

[Download HTML](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Qn733dfTvGJMLeJXFhCWX9onr38WwPr/view?usp=sharing)

Please check the picture,

I want to click on the red circle part.

But there is a JavaScript popup that blocks me.

[image]

I tried the following code

The first is to click the menu button directly

`driver.find_element_by_id('menu_li').click()`

The second is to click the close button of the popup window.

`driver.find_element_by_id('closeBtn').click()`

Answer (score 0):

you can try using . selenium actionchains

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver.get(url)
action = ActionChains(driver)
firstLevelMenu = driver.find_element_by_id('menu_li')
action.move_to_element(firstLevelMenu).perform()
secondLevelMenu = driver.find_element_by_id('closeBtn')
action.move_to_element(secondLevelMenu).perform()
secondLevelMenu.click()
```

read more about actionchains on this [link](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html)

Comment: hi,is error ```selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"closeBtn"}```

Comment: inspect the element and check if the id is right. 
you can also use driver.find_element_by_xpath()